# SICSTus Emacs Interface - Installation

Tags: shell, load

I am currently trying to install the SICSTus Emacs Interface on Ubuntu to use Emacs to program in Prolog, but it seems that I am too stupid to do so.
On
https://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/4.3.5/html/relnotes/Emacs-Installation.html#Emacs-Installation it says I just need to load the file `sicstus_emacs-init.el`.
I am totally new to Emacs. I suppose "load the file" means I should open it with Emacs. But how am I able to execute the code to configure the Interface?

Answer (score 1):

For reference, the documentation says this:

```
The easiest way to configure the Emacs interface is to load the file
sicstus_emacs_init.el from your .emacs file. It will find the SICStus
executable and do all initialization needed to use the SICStus Emacs
interface.
```

It means that you should put `(load "sicstus_emacs_init")` in your init file (which might be `~/.emacs` or `~/.emacs.d/init.el`).

Of course, Emacs still need to know where this file is. Emacs will look in every directory in the variable `load-path` for this file, so you might want to first add the SICSTus installation directory to that list. The documentation says:

```
The default installation location for the Emacs files is
<prefix>/lib/sicstus-4.3.5/emacs/ on UNIX platforms and
C:\Program Files\SICStus Prolog VC14 4.3.5\emacs\ under Windows.
```

Thus you would add something like this to your init file, making sure to adjust it for the location where you have actually installed the software:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "<prefix>/lib/sicstus-4.3.5/emacs")
```

You might want to read [chapter 27.8 Libraries of Lisp Code for Emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Lisp-Libraries.html) of the Emacs manual for more information about how to load libraries. The manual can also be read inside of Emacs by typing `C-h i`, and choosing it from the list. You mentioned Ubuntu though, so be aware that Debian and Ubuntu and some related distributions don’t install the manual unless you install a separate package, which is stupid.

Comment: +1 for linking to the doc. You might want to mention `load-library` (perhaps in preference to `load`). And even perhaps `require`.

Comment: Perhaps, though I myself have never actually used `load-library`. Also, I think if the setup included any packages then it would mention them. Possibly it `require`s them itself.

Comment: Thanks for the help and your effort! Everything is working as it should. Maybe i just should have started with reading the Emacs manual to understand what i want to do.